# Login/User Management - Location Trust System: How to handle this in a database?

Tags: php, sql, database, authentication, trust

I am building a secure login system and would like to implement a feature which tracks the users location [IP]. I'd rather do it based on device but apparently I can't get MAC address via PHP. On account creation the [IP] is logged and noted as trusted. If the user attempts to login from a different IP the trust system will send a small verification key to their e-mail and ask them to enter the key before proceeding with the login.

How best would it be to implement this from a database perspective?

I was thinking I would create:

**TABLE**: locationTrust

**COLUMNS**: [locationTrustID], [accountID], [ip], [date]

VIA PHP I would then compare each login from the customer to the stored trusted IP's and either let them in or add a new one if they valid with key. Alternately I could add a column to the account table and store mulitple locations in one field separated by a idenifier.

Does this make sense?

Comment: I don't see how an ip address adds any value to your login system.

Comment: This will be horrible for people with dynamic IP addresses.

Comment: How else would you do identify a unique device? I've noticed a couple secure websites do this, it's not that uncommon.

Comment: Security is based on the person using the device, not the device being used.

Comment: So companies that use device authorization just do it for fun?